# Doctrine caching basics

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I do not understand the default behaviour of doctrine's caching settings and basic implications.

1. If I issue a basic query (with the default symfony & doctrine configuration) like

   ```
   $em->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->findAll()
   ```

   **is this cached in any way???**

   1.1 What about `$queryBuilder->...->getResult()`? without touching `->useXXXCache()`, **is this cached?**

   1.2 So, do I understand correctly that caching only is enabled via `$queryBuilder->...->useXXXCache()->getResult()` ?
2. Per default, all 3 caches (metadata, query and result) are set to `array`. This means, each new request has it's own cache.

   Ok, so if I use this setting, and do not perform any flushes and persists during a request that uses cached queries, then I can be sure that I will never get outdated results ? Because writes take place in an other request.
3. Is there a possibility to use a cache (result or query) by default? So to not having to set `$query->useResultCache(true)`?

Comment: Did the answer help you? If not, can you please provide a comment telling what is unclear? Otherwise, please have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I issue a basic query (with the default symfony & doctrine configuration) like `$em->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->findAll()` is this cached in any way???

It is not cached, but the entities retrieved are *managed* by the entity manager (during the script’s lifetime). This means that if, for instance, the `findAll()` call gives you the entities with IDs 1, 2, 3 and you would subsequently call `find(1)`, it would not trigger a new DB query.

However, if you’re executing a DQL query (directly or through the query builder), it will always trigger a DB query, even if the result set is the same. At least entities already managed wouldn’t need to be hydrated anymore.

> 1.1 What about `$queryBuilder->...->getResult()`? without touching `->useXXXCache()`, is this cached?

Nope.

> 1.2 So, do I understand correctly that caching only is enabled via `$queryBuilder->...->useXXXCache()->getResult()`?

Yes.

> Per default, all 3 caches (metadata, query and result) are set to array. This means, each new request has it's own cache.

Yes. You can easily set up different caches, e.g. APCu, Redis or Memcache. However, it is recommended to use those only in production environments.

> Ok, so if I use this setting, and do not perform any flushes and persists during a request that uses cached queries, then I can be sure that I will never get outdated results ? Because writes take place in an other request.

If you’re afraid that concurrent requests mess up your data, use transactions and locking.

> Is there a possibility to use a cache (result or query) by default? So to not having to set `$query->useResultCache(true)`?

No.